# How would I go about implementing CSRF to certain routes or route groups in Slim Framework PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, backbone.js, csrf, slim

In an attempt to making a web application secure, I am trying to implement CSRF in it. What I have done so far is, use CSRFGuard middleware supplied together with Slim-Extras, along with a global ajaxSetup as follows.

at end.php

`$app->add(new \Slim\Extras\Middleware\CsrfGuard('csrf')); // load the middleware`

at Session.js file (backbone js)

`$.ajaxSetup({ headers : { 'X-CSRF-Token' : csrf } });`

I have also updated the CSRFGuard Middleware to check headers for CSRF tokens along with the default post variables check.

The front end of the application uses the structure mentioned here at [Advance Security in Backbone Applications](http://danialk.github.io/blog/2013/07/28/advanced-security-in-backbone-application/)

The back end simply uses the Slim Framework along with Slim-Extras and Twig Template Engine.

As of Now, every request to the server side is being checked for CSRF token. However, there are some callback routes, that would handle POST/PUT data from other web apps. Hence, I would like to know of a way I could handle this with Slim Framework. My guess would be, I need to use CSRF protection for some routes?

Comment: I have the same problem... have you found a solution ?

Comment: I found a temporary solution. Created a customized version of CsrfGuard class and added a whitelist of urls during the check.